# viewcontroller(xib)-random call in ios7

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib, arc4random

Does the following code call the viewcontrollers randomly?
Here controller is my NSArray,where all my viewcontroller names are stored.

```
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:arc4random_uniform(controllers.count)      animated:YES];
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arc4random_uniform` returns integer value. If you want to implement this, then you might need to use this -

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:[controllers objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(controllers.count)] animated:YES];
```

Update -

```
NSString *className = [controllers objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(controllers.count)];
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController*)[[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: -[__NSCFConstantString useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x41c1c

Comment: share your ideas about calling the view controller randomly

Comment: looks like the controller which it is trying to push is not initialized which is causing issue. How you have stored controllers in array??

Comment: yes stored in nsarray *array = [[nsarray alloc]initwithobject:@"viewcontroller1",@"viewcontroller2",nil];

Comment: it is not loading as it is just a string instead of controller object, check updated answer.